# Easiest way to replace multiple config lines in a Bash script with Ansible

Tags: bash, ansible

I'm trying to replace some variables in a bash script with Ansible. Here is some part of the original function (from a much bigger script):

```bash
set_variable_defaults() {
    : "${MK_LIBDIR:="/usr/lib/check_mk_agent"}"
    : "${MK_CONFDIR:="/etc/check_mk"}"
    : "${MK_VARDIR:="/var/lib/check_mk_agent"}"
    : "${MK_LOGDIR:="/var/log/check_mk_agent"}"
    : "${MK_BIN:="/usr/bin"}"
}
```

And what I want instead:

```bash
set_variable_defaults() {
    : "${MK_LIBDIR:="/share/usr/lib/check_mk_agent"}"
    : "${MK_CONFDIR:="/share/etc/check_mk"}"
    : "${MK_VARDIR:="/share/var/lib/check_mk_agent"}"
    : "${MK_LOGDIR:="/var/log/check_mk_agent"}"
    : "${MK_BIN:="/share"}"
}
```

I tried `lineinfile` and `replace` but I'm getting issues with the fact that my regexes and lines have double-quotes, colons, slashes and `{}`. What would be the best approach to do this with Ansible?

Comment: have you tried to `template` the whole script file?

Comment: @CarlosMonroyNieblas the script sometimes change, I download it from the internet, but the variables are always the same from a version to another.

Comment: You don't control the version of the file distributed to your hosts?

Comment: @CarlosMonroyNieblas It's a monitoring script updated by a 3rd party every week or so. I deploy it to a bunch of VMs, but one of these VMs has some specific requirements and that's forcing me to change some of the default variables.

Comment: See the `regex_escape` filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work, the idea is to put the regexes in variables to then use `regex_escape()` as suggested by @Zeitounator in the comments.

```yaml
- name: adjust agent to work in HaOS
  ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
    path: /path/to/my/file
    regexp: '{{ item.regexp }}'
    line: '{{ item.line }}'
  with_items:
    - { regexp: '{{ MK_LIBDIR | regex_escape() }}', line: '    : "${MK_LIBDIR:="/share/usr/lib/check_mk_agent"}"' }
    - { regexp: '{{ MK_CONFDIR | regex_escape() }}', line: '    : "${MK_CONFDIR:="/share/etc/check_mk"}"' }
    - { regexp: '{{ MK_VARDIR | regex_escape() }}', line: '    : "${MK_VARDIR:="/share/var/lib/check_mk_agent"}"' }
    - { regexp: '{{ MK_BIN | regex_escape() }}', line: '    : "${MK_BIN:="/share"}"' }
  vars:
    - MK_LIBDIR: '    : "${MK_LIBDIR:="/usr/lib/check_mk_agent"}"'
    - MK_CONFDIR: '    : "${MK_CONFDIR:="/etc/check_mk"}"'
    - MK_VARDIR: '    : "${MK_VARDIR:="/var/lib/check_mk_agent"}"'
    - MK_BIN: '    : "${MK_BIN:="/usr/bin"}"'
```